# Como hacer que el date picker cargue 2 dígitos en lugar de 1

Tags: android, android-studio, datepicker

Simple, mi `datepicker` carga por defecto 1 digito cuando el mes y el dia son así, ejemplo enero=1  febrero=2 y así sucesivamente, es decir al cargar la fecha impuesta se vera "21-1-2017" ( en el dia de hoy ) y necesito que estos sean vistos "21-01-2017"

Answer (score 3):

Debes de utilizar la clase SimpleDateFromat para formatear tu cadena que se obtiene del picker

```
SimpleDateFormat fechaFormateada = new SimpleDateFormat(“dd-MM-yyyy”);
String strFecha = “21-01-2017”; //Esta es la fecha que vas obtuviste del picker
Date fecha = null;
fecha = fechaFormateada.parse(strFecha);
```

Comment: es importante recalcar que el formato que estas usando en estos momentos es: d-M-yyyy o dd-M-yyyy. (tu ejemplo no aclara si el día esta en 1 o 2 digitos)
Si quieres dos dígitos siempre en día y mes, debes usar dd-MM-yyyy.

Esta es la respuesta correcta

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CargaEvento extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "CargaEvento";  
    private EditText m_DisplayDate;
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_carga_evento);

        m_DisplayDate = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtfechainicio);


        m_DisplayDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

                DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(CargaEvento.this,mDateSetListener,year,month,day);
                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.WHITE));

                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        mDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                month=month+1;
                Log.d(TAG,"onDateSet: dd-mm-yyy : " + day +"-" + month + "-" + year);

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
                String date_str = day +"-" + month + "-" + year; // String obtenido de DatePicker

                try {

                    Date date_date; // variable para pasar de String a Date
                    date_date = sdf.parse(date_str); // paso la variable String a Date

                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy"); // nuevo simple date format para
                                                                                            // pasar de Date a String por segunda vez
                    String date_str2 = formatter.format(date_date); // variable para pasar Date a String
                    m_DisplayDate.setText(date_str2); // muestro en objeto el String retransformado

                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        };

    }
}
```

Comment: Hola Nelz, bienvenido. Si esto trata de ser una respuesta, has de pulsar [edit] para añadir más informacion explicando el codigo. mira [answer] para más info. Un saludo